# How to expand $() inside find -exec command

Tags: shell, find

I have a mongodump which I want to import apparently I'm looking to do this using the `find` command. Something like this:

```
find *.bson -type f -exec echo mongoimport --db=abc --collection=$(echo '{}' | sed  s/.bson//g) {} \;
```

What I'm looking isn't get evaluate what I need is

```
mongoimport --db=abc --collection=a a.bson
```

but I'm getting is

```
mongoimport --db=abc --collection=a.bson a.bson
```

My version of using `sed` to strip the `.bson` suffix from `'{}'` isn't working.  I know its not a blocker but I felt if that is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just don't.  Instead of trying to wrangle shell quoting rules to work, just do `find ... -exec /path/to/my/script {} \;`  It is not worth the effort to avoid writing a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem twofold:

1. **Shell expansions:** Before a command is executed in a shell environment, the shell (sh/bash/ksh/zsh) will perform a sequence of expansions to build up the actual command that is being executed. There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion. Hence, before the `find` command will be executed, it will perform all substitutions, including the command substitution located in the `exec` statement. Ergo, the command is equivalent to:

   ```
   $ find *.bson -type f -exec echo mongoimport --db=abc --collection={} {} \;
   ```

   A way forward would be to prohibit the command substitution by using single-quotes, however this leads to problem two.
2. **`find`'s exec statement is limited:** The command that -exec can execute is limited to an external utility with optional arguments. Various shell features are therefor not recognized. To use shell built-ins, functions, conditionals, pipelines, redirections etc. directly with `-exec` is not possible, unless wrapped in something like a `sh -c` child shell.

Hence the answer would be something in the line of:

```
$ find *.bson -type f -exec /usr/bin/sh -c 'echo mongoimport --db=abc --collection=$(echo {} | sed  s/.bson//g) {}' \;
```

Comment: Smart and elegant solution using sub-sub-shell. I dislike `xarg` discrepancies and propose another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting different strategy to this problem.

Use `find` with option `-printf` to prepare your commands.

The result will be list of commands to execute (command per line).

After inspecting and testing the commands, save `find` command output into a file and run the file (as a `bash` script).

Or just run directly into `bash` command.

#### 1. `find` result inspection:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bson" -printf "mongoimport --db=abc --collection=%f %f\n" | sed s/.bson//
```

Notice `sed` replacement only on first `.bson` match. Do **not** use `g` option.

#### 2. Run processed and inspected `find` output.

```
 bash <<< $(find . -type f -name "*.bson" -printf "mongoimport --db=abc --collection=%f %f\n" | sed s/.bson//)
```